# SMTPServerDisconnected at /account/signup/ using django-allauth on Google Cloud Run and Workspace smtp-relay

Tags: python, django, docker, smtp, google-cloud-run

I've attempted the various recommended config options and my SMTP relay works perfectly locally, but fails when deployed in my Google Cloud Run service with the following error:

```
SMTPServerDisconnected at /account/signup/
Connection unexpectedly closed
...
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 67, in open
    self.connection.starttls(keyfile=self.ssl_keyfile, certfile=self.ssl_certfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 764, in starttls
    self.ehlo_or_helo_if_needed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 607, in ehlo_or_helo_if_needed
    (code, resp) = self.helo()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 436, in helo
    (code, msg) = self.getreply()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/smtplib.py", line 400, in getreply
    raise SMTPServerDisconnected("Connection unexpectedly closed")
```

The relevant settings for my SMTP config from `settings.py`:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp-relay.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = env('EMAIL_HOST_USER', default=None) # according to the traceback the credential env variables are pulling through correctly
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = env('EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD', default=None)
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

I am building from a Dockerfile, so as an additional attempt to fix, I added `EXPOSE 587/tcp`, which seems to have no impact.
This [doc](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail) from Google seems to suggest there is nothing blocking it, although it doesn't explicitly refer to the Cloud Run service.

Less secure apps is also enabled and I am using a generated app password from the email host account.

Unsure if there are any settings I am missing to account for my setup on google cloud run or dockerfile, so any ideas/fixes would be much appreciated. Can update with other specific info if needed.

Edit: after a lot more trial and error, decided to give another SMTP provider a go to see if that was the issue, and got it working using SocketLabs free tier without any issue. So seems like the issue is with my Google workspace SMTP config, rather than the Docker image or Google Cloud Run setup. I'll open a support ticket with Google admin and report back if it's revsolved.

Edit 2: My support request didn't lead to a resolution. I was told my workspace/mail account config looked fine and was advised to reach out for further support from gcloud (implying it was an infra/application issue). I'm not so convinced, but regardless, I'm not interested in pursuing it further (seeing as I know it works with other providers). I switched to a more permanent setup with another provider, which covers both the email hosting and supports SMTP for a lower cost than workspace (I wasn't using any of the extra stuff that comes with workspace anyway). Still curious if anyone else comes across the same issue and finds a solution.